# Create an instance of custom button dynamically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a custom button class as follows.

```
import UIKit

class LogButtonView: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = self.tintColor.CGColor
    }

}
```

And I know how to use it in story board.

But how can I create an instance of it dynamically in `ViewController.swift` and add it to `containerView`?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let logBtn = LogButtonView() // Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

And if possible, I want all `LogButtonView` instances to be of the same size, so I set `self.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100)`. But the instances in story board seem to be of the size I dragged them to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create views in code, dont't use `init(coder:)`, use `init(frame:)` instead. And don't forget to add it in view hierarchy after creating

```
class LogButtonView: UIButton {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100))
        //other stuff
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

//viewDidLoad:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let logBtn = LogButtonView()
    self.view.addSubview(logBtn)
}
```

but I don't think you want to set frame in init of view, because it means that every LogButtonView will be in the same position. Much better approach would be:

```
class LogButtonView: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //other stuff
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

//viewDidLoad:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let logBtn = LogButtonView(frame: CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100))
    self.view.addSubview(logBtn)
}
```